# When deploying shiny app in shiny.io I get "app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object"

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

`Error in value[[3L]](cond) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted`

This is the error I am getting while deploying my shiny app in shiny.io, but the app works fine in local machine. If someone can help me, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Your chances of getting an answer will greatly increase if you provide a simple, self-contained example of your problem. This would include toy input data, your code, any error messages, and expected output. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) may be helpful.